# How to config google cloud storage credential?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, boto

I have a web application in flask python.
It is working fine with google cloud storage and it's using my .boto file which contains gs credentials.

After deploying to google app engine, it lose the authorization to get access to google storage (same buckets).

Should I also deploy my credential or just config either storage bucket or my application?

I got this error from google app engine log:

**NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials**

Comment: Does the GCS you're accessing is related to that particular app?

Comment: No. But both app and gcs bucket is under same project.